# What is happening to the pixels when I detach them from an image?

Tags: c#, image-processing, uwp, pixel

I think with this question I am asking how Bitmap Encoders/Decoders work.I create a bitmap in Windows Paint with 1 Red Pixel (BGRA=36,27,237,255) and print the image and buffer in my program, it is expected.

[image]

But if I make the image 1x2 and make the second pixel yellow (0,242,254,255), the colors sort of merge and I get an unexpected buffer.

JPEG:

[image]

PNG:

[image]

What is happening?

Also does the buffer know if the next pixel is to the left, right, down, or up? For example, If I put the yellow pixel on the right how would this influence the buffer?

Code:

```
        SoftwareBitmap detectorInput = null;
        WriteableBitmap displaySource = null;

        try
        {


            StorageFile photoFile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path + @"\Two.png");
            if (photoFile == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //this.rootPage.NotifyUser("Opening...", NotifyType.StatusMessage);

            // Open the image file and decode the bitmap into memory.

            using (IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await photoFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapDecoder decoder = await BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(fileStream);
                BitmapTransform transform = this.ComputeScalingTransformForSourceImage(decoder);

                using (SoftwareBitmap originalBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync(decoder.BitmapPixelFormat, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, transform, ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage))
                {


                    const BitmapPixelFormat InputPixelFormat = BitmapPixelFormat.Gray8;
                    if (FaceDetector.IsBitmapPixelFormatSupported(InputPixelFormat))
                    {
                        using (detectorInput = SoftwareBitmap.Convert(originalBitmap, InputPixelFormat))
                        {
                            // Create a WritableBitmap for our visualization display; copy the original bitmap pixels to wb's buffer.
                            displaySource = new WriteableBitmap(originalBitmap.PixelWidth, originalBitmap.PixelHeight);
                            originalBitmap.CopyToBuffer(displaySource.PixelBuffer);
                            Two.Source = displaySource;


                            PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync(
                                BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, // WriteableBitmap uses BGRA format 
                                BitmapAlphaMode.Straight,
                                transform,
                                ExifOrientationMode.IgnoreExifOrientation, // This sample ignores Exif orientation 
                                ColorManagementMode.DoNotColorManage
                            );

                            // An array containing the decoded image data, which could be modified before being displayed 
                            byte[] sourcePixels = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
                            two = sourcePixels;
                            foreach (byte sourcePixel in sourcePixels)
                            {
                                TwoText.Text += sourcePixel + " ";
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return;
                        //this.rootPage.NotifyUser("PixelFormat '" + InputPixelFormat.ToString() + "' is not supported by FaceDetector", NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return;
            // this.rootPage.NotifyUser(ex.ToString(), NotifyType.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is a good description of the JPEG encoding process here... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG#Encoding Note that if you save as PNG, or GIF or other lossless format, you will get back exactly your original pixels without these effects - it is only because JPEG is lossy that these effects occur.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did it with PNG, same problem, but slightly different results